# Can a creature with a natural weapon that has reach make an attack through the Antilife Shell spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, weapons, natural-weapon, reach

The [*Antilife Shell*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antilife-shell) spell states:

> An affected creature can cast spells or make attacks with ranged or reach weapons through the barrier.

This suggests that a human could attack with a glaive, since the weapon can reach the full 10 feet through the shell and strike the caster.

Does this include monsters whose natural weapons have a reach of 10 feet or greater? For example, a dragon's tail attack which has a 15-foot reach or a T-Rex's bite which has a 10-foot reach.

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/144611/42959

Answer (score 10):

The description of [Antilife Shell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antilife-shell) describes that

> The barrier prevents an affected creature from passing or reaching through.

The part about "reaching through" seems applicable here: the intent is clearly that no part of the creature's body can make it through the barrier.  Natural weapons are by definition part of a creature's body, and can therefore not reach through to attack targets within an *antilife shell*.  (Ranged natural weapons, such as a manticore's tail spikes, are no longer attached to the body and should go through.)

Comment: Where do manticore tail spikes come in on this? They are a natural weapon technically. Also, I'm not sure there is a manufactured melee weapon with enough reach to hit a target inside on an antilife shell.